# Run Keras.NET models in different threads in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, numpy, keras, access-violation

Since `Keras.Models.Sequential` takes a little bit of time to get ready for utilization, that makes a program with a user interface to freeze for a moment, and obviously would annoy the user.
Therefore, I am trying to create models, fit and predict data in a different thread in the background, then return results to the main user interface.

I've tried creating a model and fit it in a different thread. Then insert the model in a global variable in the main thread. But if I try predicting from the model of the global variable, it freezes the user interface forever with no results.

Now I am using the following method:
`main` function for example:

```
public int main() 
{
    Thread modelThread1 = new Thread(() => runModel(
        np.array(new float[] { 0, 1, 4, 6 }), 
        np.array(new float[] { 0, 1, 4, 6 })));
    modelThread1.Start();

    Thread modelThread2 = new Thread(() => runModel(
        np.array(new float[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 }), 
        np.array(new float[] { 1, 3, 5, 7 })));
    modelThread2.Start();
}
```

This is a simple function:

```
private void runModel(NDarray xs, NDarray ys)
{
    Keras.Models.Sequential model = new Keras.Models.Sequential();
    model.Add(new Dense(1, input_shape: new Shape(1)));
    model.Compile(optimizer: "sgd", loss: "mean_squared_error");
    model.Fit(xs, ys, epochs: 500, verbose: 0);

    Console.WriteLine(model.Predict(new float[] { 11 }, verbose: 0));
}
```

If I run this, it shows me the following error:

> System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way of making that.
After a little bit of research and trials, I found that C# Tensorflow tools as "Keras.Models.Sequential" and "Numpy" must run on the same thread. Therefore, I just have to create only one thread in the background, which deals with tensorflow stuff, and make it wait for instruction from the main user interface.
The way of doing so is answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999373/passing-data-between-threads-in-c-sharp).

In my example, I created a class called "TFBackThread":

```
class TFBackThread
{
    public readonly AutoResetEvent _signal = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    public readonly ConcurrentQueue<object[]> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<object[]>();

    public TFBackThread()
    {
    }

    public void ThreadServer()
    {
        // Initialize the model
        Keras.Models.Sequential model = new Keras.Models.Sequential();
        model.Add(new Dense(1, input_shape: new Shape(1)));
        model.Compile(optimizer: "sgd", loss: "mean_squared_error");
        while (true)
        {
            _signal.WaitOne();

            object[] item = null;
            while (_queue.TryDequeue(out item))
            {
                // Check which function is selected
                switch ((string)item[0])
                {
                    case "fit":
                        fit(model, np.array((float[])item[1]), np.array((float[])item[2]), (int)item[3]);
                        break;
                    case "predict":
                        predict(model, (float[])item[1]);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void fit(Keras.Models.Sequential model, NDarray xs, NDarray ys, int epochs)
    {
        model.Fit(xs, ys, epochs: epochs, verbose: 0);
    }

    private void predict(Keras.Models.Sequential model, float[] x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(model.Predict(x, verbose: 0));
        // Return result to main user interface
    }
}
```

Now the way I use this class is as follows:

```
    TFBackThread tFBackThread;
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tFBackThread = new TFBackThread();
        Thread TFThread = new Thread(() => tFBackThread.ThreadServer());
        TFThread.Start();
        tFBackThread._queue.Enqueue(new object[] { "fit", new float[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 }, new float[] { 1, 3, 5, 7 }, 500 });
        tFBackThread._queue.Enqueue(new object[] { "predict", new float[] { 11 } });
        tFBackThread._signal.Set();
    }
```

And you can even call it from an event handler as follows:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tFBackThread._queue.Enqueue(new object[] { "predict", new float[] { 23 } });
        tFBackThread._signal.Set();
    }
```

This is not the answer I am looking for. However, at least this trick makes the user interface's thread less freezy.
I hope this might help some one in the future. Or anyone might share a better method.

Answer (score 0):

Run this once...

```
np.arange(1); // force numpy initialisation, required before PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads()
Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads(); // allow different threads
```

Then you need to use the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) to lock access to the Python engine exclusively for only one thread at a time by wrapping any code that calls into Python in a `using` block like this...

```
using (Py.GIL()) 
{
    // any code calling Python here i.e. Numpy, Keras etc... 
}
```

See [Multi-threading (Must read!)](https://github.com/SciSharp/Numpy.NET/blob/master/README.md#multi-threading-must-read) which came out of the following issue...

[NDarray error initialization inside RestApi method (C#/WebApi project)](https://github.com/SciSharp/Numpy.NET/issues/26)

The simple Web API examples [here](https://github.com/SciSharp/Numpy.NET/tree/master/src/Examples) may also be of interest.